# How to notify other users that the a certain modal is open

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sockets, meteor, socket.io

Given the situation:

A user (customer agent) should know if the modal is currently open by other customer support to avoid conflicts on processing the data. So example I opened the modal, it should notify the other users that "hey this is being processed right now, go do other stuff"

Since the project is using meteor.js I considered to take advantage of its real-time feature. I was thinking of storing (MongoDB) a state on every modal if it is open or not (because every modal is a data), of course we can set the "close state" if the user closes the modal (in case he did not proceed processing the data), however what if the user accidentally closed the browser tab / browser window / power outage? then the data is set as "open" in the database forever.

I also considered the use of sockets. (i.e. socketIO) so it will publish to the other users the data of the current modal that is open every time a user opens a modal, so user opened a modal -> socket notify other users on what modal is open. but what if the user opened a modal -> socket notify other users -> then another user logged in to the system (which means he did not get the socket notification and might end up opening the same modal.

So any recomendations / ideas / tips you wanna share?

I'm using Meteor.js, React js, MongoDB as my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve what your looking for with `socket.io` an example of how you would handle notifying other users is by simply creating a `Map()` within the server. This holds information about currently open modals and the users accessing them. I have outlined some code below that could give you and idea of how to do it:

```
//client side
function modals(socket) {

    this.sendModalOpen = (modalIdentifier) => {

        socket.emit('openedModal', {
            modal: modalIdentifier
        });
    };

    this.closeModal = () => {
        socket.emit('closedModal', {
            modal: modalIdentifier
        });
    };

}


socket.on('recModalInfo', (data) => {
    for (let x = 0; x < data.info.length; x++) {
        console.log(data.info[x][0] + " has open " + data.info[x][1]);
    }
});

//server side
let modal = new Map();

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    //Here we are sending any new connections a list of all current modals being viewed with Identifiers.
    //You could send all of the items inside the map() using map.entries

    let currentInfo = [];

    modal.forEach((value, key) => {
        currentInfo.push([key, value]);
    });

    socket.emit('recModalInfo', {
        info: currentInfo
    });

    socket.on('openedModal', (data) => {
        modal.set(socket.id, data.modalIdentifier);
    });

    socket.on('closedModal', (data) => {
        modal.delete(socket.id);
    });

});
```

I have included client and serverside, but as your obviously not using vanilla JavaScript here the clientside code is more of a representation of what needs to happen that you can adapt.

> but what if the user opened a modal -> socket notify other users ->
>   then another user logged in to the system (which means he did not get
>   the socket notification and might end up opening the same modal.

When a user connects to the server and a socket is created the `io.on('connection', (socket)=>{  });` Is always ran which allows us to then send out an emit detailing all of the current modals open and a identifier.

> A user (customer agent) should know if the modal is currently open by
>   other customer support to avoid conflicts on processing the data.

As your client will receive information about the modals currently open you can either choose to make them not available on the DOM by not rendering the code used to access the modal. You could also process a check on the map if it's a 1-1 scenario and build further functionality if say a manager or a special individual wants to view the modal for some reason or just not at all.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that. thanks. but do I need to trigger the event over and over again or is it automatic that the event will send once another user logged in? I might try playing with socketio

Comment: It will process the event `connection` whenever someone connects to the page and is served a socket, allowing you to send back information about what is currently being viewed or not allowing for changes or to simply not render buttons / links for modals.

Comment: To clarify the code inside `connection` is processed each time someone connects. You can also add a `socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{})` that will run whenever someone disconnects, allowing you to grab any open modals they may have and close them inside the `Mongodb`.

Comment: Not even an upvote for all the time I spent trying to answer your question? :-(

Comment: Oh I see, It's clear for me now, Thanks! Gotta try this. sorry I've just read your comments (was asleep hours ago)

Comment: Yes, but it's not working as expected, this is what happens:

user1: connected -> broadcast to other user about the action -> other logged in users received it -> user 3 logged in -> didn't received the event since I connected late.

So I ended up storing it somewhere in mongo and running a cron job to check it every now and then (since we are already using it anyways) coz installing another package seems to be an overkill for a single function. :3

Comment: Hmm sounds like your not storing the event centrally for the third user in the scenario to catch it, providing you don't have a large amount of modals the amount of data taken by the memory should be low enough to hold this on the server. Which means your access and write speeds should be very high not causing an event to ever be missed.

Comment: I see, aha, let me try this approach again on my next project. Since I'm planning to build a different system that may use this function. Thanks for the suggestion. (And since my solution was already accepted by my boss :3)

Comment: No worries, if I my answer helped you out can you mark it as correct? :D